# bcp '-C' option not supported

Tags: sql-server, linux, bcp

I have bcp version#11.0.1790.0 installed in Linux machine. I want to "bcp in" data to SQL Server from a data file. My data file is in UTF-8 format and I want to load the data to sql server in ISO_1 format. For this I tried using -C option which is used to specify the code page. But bcp says : 
`-C option is not supported in this release.` 
**Is there any alternative for the -C option. Is there any specific reason that -C option is not supported in bcp for linux but supported in bcp for Windows?**

Thanks,

Manoj

Comment: Probably the team never got around to developing it: it was probably written to use the Win32 character set APIs and so would have needed (admittedly simple) porting work on Linux. Can you BCP the data into a different table on your server and then copy it across to the real table with the character transform?

Comment: Well my problem is solved I created the data file in UTF8 and loaded in the same format. '-C' option was not required with bcp's Linux version. However when using win Bcp then only u need to specify code page.

Comment: @ManojSuyal - You are allowed to submit the answer to your own question, and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved I created the data file in UTF8 and loaded in the same format. '-C' option was not required with bcp's Linux version. However when using windows Bcp then only we need to specify code page..